# Why does the Riesz Representation Theorem establish an antilinear correspondence between bras and kets?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, conventions, complex-numbers

I am reading Ballentine's *Quantum Mechanics* and, in the mathematical preqrequisites, he asserts that, **by construction**, the Riesz Representation Theorem establishes an antilinear correspondence between bras and kets in the sense that, if $\left|F \right\rangle$ has as its dual $\langle F |$, then $c_1 \left|F_1 \right\rangle+ c_2 \left|F_2 \right\rangle$ is dual to $c_1^* \langle F_1 | + c_2^* \langle F_2 |.$

In previous QM courses, this has been laid down as an axiom, so I am hoping someone can elucidate for me how it follows **by construction** from the Riesz Representation Theorem, as given by Ballentine:

[image]

It must have something to do with the line below "Now construct the following vector:, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

EDIT: It seems to me that it follows from our choice to make the first slot of the inner product antilinear. I guess hazy terms like "correspondence" just confuse me though.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what the question is.  If you hand me a vector $f$ I can hand you a continuous linear functional $F : \phi \mapsto \langle f,\phi\rangle$.  If you hand me a continuous linear functional $F$, then I can hand you a vector $f = \sum_i \underbrace{\overline{F(\varphi_i)} }_{\in \mathbb C}\ \varphi_i$, where $\{\varphi_i\}$ is any orthonormal basis of the Hilbert space and the line denotes complex conjugation.

Note that the fact that this indeed a vector in the Hilbert space is trivial for finite-dimensional spaces, and follows from the fact that all continuous linear functionals are bounded for infinite-dimensional spaces.

One can show without too much difficulty that this correspondence amounts to an isomorphism - a one-to-one pairing between vectors and continuous linear functionals.  This pairing is antilinear in the following sense: if $f$ and $g$ are vectors, $F$ and $G$ the corresponding continuous linear functionals, and $\alpha\in \mathbb C$ then
$$f + g \iff F + G \qquad \text{and} \qquad \alpha f \iff \overline\alpha F$$

Both statements can be proven straightforwardly from the pairing defined above.

---

> It seems to me that it follows from our choice to make the first slot of the inner product antilinear.

Yes, that's right. Indeed, we can go the other way: given a vector $f$ we can produce a continuous, *anti*linear functional $\widetilde F:\phi \mapsto \langle \phi,f\rangle$, and given a continuous antilinear functional $\widetilde F$ we can produce a vector $f = \sum_i \widetilde F(\varphi_i) \varphi_i$.  This correspondence is then **linear** in the sense that
$$f + g \iff \widetilde F + \widetilde G\qquad \text{and}\qquad \alpha f \iff \alpha \widetilde F$$

Having built up all this structure, given a vector $f$ we use the shorthand $F \equiv \langle f|$ for its linear functional partner, and $\widetilde F \equiv |f\rangle$ for its antilinear functional partner, while defining $\langle f|g\rangle := \langle f,g\rangle$.  This provides the rigorous underpinning of the bra-ket notation which is in universal use among working physicists.

Comment: Thanks for this superb answer! If I may, I should just note that (I believe) "orthonormal" should be added before "basis" in your third line.

Comment: @1729_SR Yep, you're right. Thanks.